# Drupal - How to do a search hook

Tags: php, drupal, hook, drupal-hooks

I want to customize my search page (actually the results) and I've read on the internet about Drupal Hooks. I've copied the prefab Drupal `hook_search_execute()` function and replaced all it's content with `echo "OK"; die();` but the site simply won't die, it just continues the search as if nothing happened.

I've placed the `hook_search_execute()` function in one of my custom modules which is 100% activated, so it should work.

Any help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems for search_execute to work, I also had to decfine the search_info hook.

Answer (score 1):

You haven´t said which Drupal Version you are using, but for Drupal 6 you have to name the `hook_search()` in your module `YOUR_MODULE_NAME_search()`. The hooks represent a naming scheme.

Comment: I am using Drupal 7 if that helps. I've tried the same thing with `hook_search_execute()` and still nothing...

Comment: It seems as if there is no hook called `hook_search`. You can see a list of all defined hooks of drupal 7 [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/group/hooks/7).

EDIT:
Now I get it. You also have to name the function `YOUR_MODULE_NAME_search_execute()`.

Comment: I've named my hook `mod_front_search_execute()` (mod_front is my module -- tried both with uppercase and lowercase letters) and still the same happens, the search runs without dying.

Comment: Have you flushed your caches since you implemented the hook with the correct name? Hook implementations are cached in Drupal 7 so the new one won't be picked up into you clear that cache.

Comment: Yes, have tried that too. I've also tried doing the same thing on the `form_alter` hook on a fresh Drupal 7.8 version and at first it didn't work, just like on this site, but I've enabled the testing module and now it works. I've tried that on my site too, but it doesn't seem to work. Does testing have to be enabled in order for hooks to work?

Comment: Now I've disabled the Test module and it still works. It may be some caching there, but not sure where, I've cleared the cache from Configuration -> Performance...